# Manually set location for mscorlib.dll in Mono mcs compiler

Tags: macos, compilation, mono

I'm trying to include a standalone mono compiler in my application and trying to remove all references to the actual mono framework in the system. I'm on OSX and I've managed to get mcs running but by the time it gets to actual compiling it claims it can't find mscorlib.dll in /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/etc . Is there a way to manually set the path to mscorlib.dll?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to use Mono 3.2 or newer for this to work. Then you pass -nostdlib and -noconfig compiler options. Both options combined means no default referenced assemblies will be loaded by C# compiler. You can now reference any custom assemblies or mscorlib and compiler will use them instead of the default ones.